# MongoTemplate Bean Instantiation failed

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, tomcat, web-applications

I Am Trying to do basic Spring WebApp of mongo Crud Operations. When i deploy war file in apache tomcat and access the url , i receive Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate Error .

My Servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <mongo:mongo id="mongod" host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" />
    <mongo:db-factory dbname="employee" />
    <mongo:repositories base-package="MongoFunction.Repository"/>
    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    </bean>


    <context:component-scan base-package="MongoFunction" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

My web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
        "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <display-name>MongoMaven</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MongoMaven</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MongoMaven</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mongoDb.employee</groupId>
  <artifactId>MongoDbWebApp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>MongoDbWebApp Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>MongoDbWebApp</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Error Stack

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/MongoMaven-servlet.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionServiceFactory.createDefaultConversionService()Lorg/springframework/core/convert/support/GenericConversionService;
19:45:01.063 [http-nio-8080-exec-61] ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/MongoMaven-servlet.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionServiceFactory.createDefaultConversionService()Lorg/springframework/core/convert/support/GenericConversionService;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1648)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:827)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:701)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:715)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:590)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:529)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:773)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/MongoMaven-servlet.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionServiceFactory.createDefaultConversionService()Lorg/springframework/core/convert/support/GenericConversionService;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367)
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionServiceFactory.createDefaultConversionService()Lorg/springframework/core/convert/support/GenericConversionService;
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:184)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:300)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionServiceFactory.createDefaultConversionService()Lorg/springframework/core/convert/support/GenericConversionService;
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.<init>(MappingMongoConverter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.getDefaultMongoConverter(MongoTemplate.java:1691)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:189)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:175)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:172)
    ... 51 common frames omitted
```

I Know it is better to use SpringBoot than Spring , but this is an assignment given by the company only to use spring . Any help would be appreciated :-D

Comment: According this pom.xml, you use a very old version of `spring-data-mongodb-1.2.0`, which dependent on spring-core-3.1.4,  but your project use spring-core-5.1.4. the `GenericConversionService ` class is not compliant, so it throw NoSuchMethod error. Maybe you should use newer version of `spring-data-mongodb`